# Novel about dystopian boarding house featuring baby burgers

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to find a novel that was too dark and disturbing for me to handle when I was younger.

I suspect it was written some time in the 80s - early 90s.

It involves a protagonist who is taken away from his family as a child and forced to live in a horrible kind of boarding house.

There is also a part where he sees commercials advertising ground-up baby burgers.

I don't think I ever got more than a third through it because it was too harsh for me. But it seemed like the character was going to go on a quest to try to overthrow some kind of computer system that was controlling the country/world.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: This is interesting, but what part of it was dystopian, or otherwise SFF related?

Comment: @Möoz - "computer system that was controlling the country/world" " commercials advertising ground-up baby burgers."